# elasticsearch "more like this" in elastic4s boolean query

Tags: scala, elasticsearch, elastic4s

I am using elastic4s 1.5.10 and trying to build up a query that I prepared on elasticsarch REST endpoint. Now trying to rewrite to elastic4s dsl.

```
POST /index_name/type/_search
{
    "_source":{"include":["name","surname"]},
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "more_like_this": {
                  "fields": ["desc"],
                  "ids": ["472825948"],
                  "min_term_freq":0,
                  "max_query_terms":200
               }
            },
            {
               "match": {"city": "London"}
            }, 
            {
               "match": {"operation": "add"}
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

The goal of this query is get similar items to 472825948 which has the same operation (add) in the same city (London).

My attempt in elastic4s follows:

```
es_client.execute{
      search in  s"$storage_folder/${typ.name()}" query bool(    
        must(
          morelike id adId in s"$storage_folder/${typ.name()}" fields("desc") minTermFreq(0) maxQueryTerms(200),
          matchQuery(field="city",value = "London"),
          matchQuery(field="operation",value = "add"))
      )sourceInclude("name","surname")
    }
  }
```

"morelike" doesn't work in this context. Either the query as it is in raw json doesn't make sense or elastic4s doesn't support this or ...

Could someone help?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for completeness adding response I got here as well.
`morelike`e is for a request type, `morelikeThisQuery` is the correct form of the query. So the resulted query should look like as follows

```
es_client.execute{
      search in  s"$storage_folder/${typ.name()}" query bool(    
        must(
          morelikeThisQuery fields("desc")  ids(adId) minTermFreq(0) maxQueryTerms(200),
          matchQuery(field="city",value = "London"),
          matchQuery(field="operation",value = "add"))
      )sourceInclude("name","surname")
    }
  }
```